# How to asynchronously reduce a variable's value while allowing the user to interact with the program?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am making a game in which a player has three values; hunger, temperature, thirst. These three stats are meant to continuously decrease i.e, every *one* second, all three stats decrease by *one*. But the values shouldn't be displayed on the screen. Meanwhile, as the stats are decreasing, the user is supposed to be playing the game. The stats are only meant to be displayed when the user presses "e". Here is my code and what I have tried:

```py
import time

hunger = 100
thirst = 100
temperature = 100
print("You've woken up after a plane crash. What you do and where you go is up to you. Just watch out for the elements.")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    hunger -= 1
    temperature -= 1
    thirst -= 1
    stat = input("Enter command: ")
    if stat == "e":
        print("Your hunger is:",hunger,"Your thirst is",thirst, "Your temperature is",temperature)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to decrease the player's stats while he is playing you can use the `while` loop in a different thread/task.

Using threads with python is very simple:

First, you have to import threading:

```
from threading import Thread
```

Now you can make a function which you will later run as a thread:

```
def decrease_stats():
    global hunger, thirst, temperature
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        hunger -= 1
        temperature -= 1
        thirst -= 1
```

After creating the function you need to run it as a thread.
Do this by typing:

```
Thread(target=decrease_stats).start()
```

Now on your main thread, you can just wait for the player to enter his command:

```
while True:
    stat = input("Enter command: ")
    if stat == "e":
    print("Your hunger is:", hunger, "Your thirst is", thirst, "Your temperature is", temperature)
```

The final result will be:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

hunger = 100
thirst = 100
temperature = 100
print("You've woken up after a plane crash. What you do and where you go is up to you. Just watch out for the elements.")

def decrease_stats():
    global hunger, thirst, temperature
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        hunger -= 1
        temperature -= 1
        thirst -= 1

Thread(target=decrease_stats).start()

while True:
    stat = input("Enter command: ")
    if stat == "e":
        print("Your hunger is:", hunger, "Your thirst is", thirst, "Your temperature is", temperature)
```